# Getting Can not access the closed file exception when uploading images using tempdata in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am storing the Images files in tempdata variable on change event of File input in MVC. When saving the data, I get save file from TempData variable and trying to save into folder. But I am getting Can not access the closed file exception. My code is like below:

```
if (TempData["imagesList"] != null)

                    imagesList = TempData["imagesList"] as List<HttpPostedFileBase>;

 if (imagesList != null)
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < imagesList.Count; i++)
                        {

                            var filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PropertyImages"), propertyId + "_" + i + "_" + imagesList[i].FileName);

                            imagesList[i].SaveAs(filename);

                        }

                    }
```

Comment: I guess that this is because you need to handle the saving of the image as soon as you upload it... are you not doing this?

Comment: I am making a list of images and showing that list on the view with holding them in TempData variable at back end. When list is completed then user save the images into folder. So, at that time I am picking the images from TempData variable to save into folder. Therefore I can not save the images at same time when uploading.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't store HttpFileBase objects, because the data on the server (the image) only lasts for the duration of the request.  After that point it is destroyed.  If you want to bunch multiple files together, you need to save them every time to a location and keep track of their filenames.

Comment: this problem is only for Images. In same way I am saving excel files and there is not any problem doing that. Is there any kind of settings or anything which is creating the problem?

Comment: I got the problem. The problem is with large size of file. Let me doing setting for that. Thanks all for giving your response.

Comment: One thing I want to mention that, file can be uploaded by maintaining the list into tempdata or session variable.

Comment: Glad to hear that you sorted it and for clarifying that it is possible.